# JPA entity with ManyToOne relationship JSON Serialization

Tags: json, entity-framework, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two JPA entities mapped by a OneToMany- ManyToOne relationship:

First entity:

```
@Entity(name = A.ENTITY_NAME)
@Table(name = A.TABLE_NAME)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class A implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -24345893264589748L;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "A";
    public static final String ENTITY_NAME = "A";

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String AName;

    private String ADescription;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "AName", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnore(true)
    private List<B> b;
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity(name = B.ENTITY_NAME)
@Table(name = B.TABLE_NAME)
public class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -24345893264589748L;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "B";
    public static final String ENTITY_NAME = "B";

    @Id
    @NotNull
    private String BName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="AName")
    private AName;

    //Properties
```

I am able to create the tables in my Oracle Database.

```
SQL> describe B;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 BNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
...
 ANAME                                          VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
```

Now i want to use these entities in my Spring MVC controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = B_CREATION_REQUEST_MAPPING, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<JSONResponse> createB(HttpServletRequest request,
            @RequestBody B b) {


            BSvc.createB(b);
            ResponseEntity<JSONResponse> response = new ResponseEntity<JSONResponse>(new JSONResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
            REST_LOGGER.info("[" + request.getRemoteAddr() + "] B object "+b.getBName()+ " has been created" );
            return response;
}
```

I have the same controller for the A object.

But when i am requesting this B controller, I have to put a A object inside the JSON although the request is not valid:

```
{ 
  "BName": "foo",
  "AName": {"AName": "bar",
            "ADescription": "too"
            }
   ...
}
```

This creates me error:

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing
```

What I want is just to put in my JSON :

```
 { 
      "BName": "foo",
      "AName": "bar",           
       ...
    }
```

And not create the object A inside the JSON. The object A is created before with the same kind of controller but I have no problem with it as there is no foreign key.

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you create a object dedicated to JSON communication instead of using the Entity ?

you can't do this :

```
{ 
      "BName": "foo",
      "AName": "bar",           
       ...
    }
```

because it will try to unserialize a String into a A object

create a DTO class

```
class BDTO {
    private String AName;
    private String Bname
}
```

bind it in your controller BDTO instead of B

```
@RequestBody BDTO bDTO
```

then you can do

```
B b = new B();
b.setBName(bDTO.getBName());
b.setAName(yoursession.find(bDTO.getAName()));

yoursession.saveOrUpdate(b);
```

**Another solution** : if you want to keep Entity as transfert object is to set only the ID in your request :

```
{ 
  "BName": "foo",
  "AName": {"AName": "bar" }
   ...
}
```

You don't have to set all the sub properties of AName only the @ID is enough, in your controller you can simply do a find() for the A object and set it on B then saveOrUpdate your B object :

```
b.setAName(yoursession.find(b.getAName().getAName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Jackson 1.9 you can define your nested class field with `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation to indicate to Jackson that a contained object should be unwrapped during serialization i.e. the contained object properties should be included among the properties of the parent.

```
public class B implements Serializable {
```

...

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="AName")
@JsonUnwrapped
private AName;
```